# Program to sort the lines of a file in c it may be in chronological order or non-chronological order

Tags: sorting

> **I need a program to sort the lines of a file and print them in an order can anyone explain**

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, but you're misinformed on what S.O. is. We answer specific programming questions. But we do not provide you with complete code/programs. If you can, please show us your effort by posting what you tried already.